# scan an image from client side pc when application is deployed in windows server 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

one of my project's feature is to scan the images. i develop this application in windows 7 and i install scanner in my pc and
 i am scanning the images successfully. now i have deployed my project in windows server. now when i try to scan the images i am receiving
 following error

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} failed due to the following error: 
 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

i am using WIA COM dll "wiaaut.dll" for scanning. i looked for the solution and found that i need to register the dll in windows
 server 2012. so i copied the dll in system32 and syswow64 both the folders and register the dll in both places. but still i 
 am getting the same error.

i could not find any considerable solution as yet. i dont know whether i am missing something or i am doing something incorrect.

please guide me the right procedure to get it done in windows server 2012.
 my main aim is to scan an image with a scanner attached in client side and my application is deployed in server side in
 "windows server 2012"

how client pc can communicate with server rightly to allow scanning from there.

furthermore i want to add that windows server 2012 is 64bit and scanner driver installed in client is 32bit, should i have
to get its 64bit version for getting access from windows server 2012. or it does not matter as its a client pc and scanner
is installed and working in client pc.

Comment: _" my main aim is to scan an image with a scanner attached in client side and my application is deployed in server side"_ - how, and more importantly: why? How is the application used? Why is the scanner not attached to the server? Also, can you try to use the Shift key now and then?

Comment: scanning from client side because the application is deployed in centralized pc and client may access the application from different locatoins using browser. on clicking a button i call the wia ShowAcquireImage method to start the scanner scanning feature (ui).